# What attacks can I block with the Paladin's Omni-Shield without taking damage?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The [N7 Paladin class](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/N7_Paladin_Sentinel) has a special [Omni-Shield](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Shield_Mastery) that can block incoming attacks, at least until it breaks. When fully upgraded, the shield has 5,250 points of health.

I'm curious if it's worth spending points to upgrade the shield to max health. **On Gold and Platinum difficulties**, can a fully upgraded Omni-Shield block the following attacks *without the player taking normal shield and health damage*? I don't care if the shield ends up breaking and staggering the player, as long as no damage is taken to normal shields and health.

1. A single rocket from a Geth Rocket-Trooper?
2. A single laser shot from a Collector Praetorian? What about for the full volley? (I think it fires twice in a single volley, right?)
3. A projectile volley from an un-possessed Collector Scion arm cannon (meaning all three shots in the volley). I don't mean the occasional grenade that it throws, just the pulse shots.
4. What about the possessed version (is there a damage difference)?
5. A projectile volley from a Geth Prime?
6. A rocket shot from a Cerberus Atlas?
7. A projectile volley from a Reaper Ravager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On gold difficulty in my experience it can usually block any of those without breaking at max health, except maybe for a possessed praetorian's full laser volley.

I do not, however, advise you staying there after you've blocked those attacks